# Is there any way to reach a spreadsheet which created by a service account?

Tags: go, google-sheets, google-sheets-api, spreadsheet, service-accounts

I created a spreadsheet using Google Sheets API with service account however I can't reach it when I try to reach with url I get an access error. I also tried set [permissions.create](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/permissions/create) but I couldn't figured out how can I find file(when I use id of spreadsheet which is in url, I take file not found error on Google Drive API) id that contain this spreadsheet. Is there any way to make spreadsheets public (maybe when creating)?

Here is my createspreadsheet function

```
func createSpreadsheet(ctx context.Context, title string, creds []byte) (*GoogleSpreadsheet, error) {

    srv, err := sheets.NewService(ctx, option.WithCredentialsJSON(creds))
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    var (
        prop = &sheets.SpreadsheetProperties{
            Title: title,
        }

        sheet = &sheets.Spreadsheet{
            Properties: prop,
        }
    )
    resp, err := srv.Spreadsheets.Create(sheet).Do() //Create request is send
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    gs := &GoogleSpreadsheet{
        SpreadSheetID:   resp.SpreadsheetId,
        SpreadSheetName: title,
        SheetID:         resp.Sheets[0].Properties.SheetId,
        SheetName:       resp.Sheets[0].Properties.Title,
        URL:             resp.SpreadsheetUrl,
        Service:         srv,
    }

    mux.Lock()
    defer mux.Unlock()
    spreadsheets[gs.SpreadSheetID] = gs
    return gs, nil
}
```

Comment: From `however I can't reach it when I try to reach with url I get an access error`, I cannot understand about the detail situation. I apologize for this. Can I ask you about the detail of it?

Comment: Please consider providing the relevant parts of the code you are working on. When you call `permissions.create`, you do it with the same account that originally created the spreadsheet?

Comment: @Tanaike Of course I can :) ,I found spreadsheet url which is created by service account from my code and I tried to reach to spreadsheet with this url (https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/edit) and I get an error that says you need to access.

Comment: @Iamblichus You are right I apologize for this, I added my function and the answer of your question is I did it with my main gmail account which is parent of my service account I dont know how to do it with service account. I couldn't understand clearly so if I can take help it would be greate.

Comment: Thank you for replying. About `I found spreadsheet url which is created by service account from my code and I tried to reach to spreadsheet with this url (docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/edit) and I get an error that says you need to access.`, in this case, how do you want to access to the Spreadsheet?

Comment: @Tanaike I want to make it public or at least I want to see the content of spreadsheet.

Comment: I would like to confirm whether my understanding for your question is correct. You want to create new Google Spreadsheet using the service account and want to publicly share the created Spreadsheet using the service account. You want to achieve this using googleapis for golang. Is my understanding correct? If my understanding is correct, can you show your whole script without your personal information? Because in your script, the script for authorizing is not included.

Answer (score 0):

#### Issue:

You created the spreadsheet with one account and tried to retrieve it with another account (one being your regular account and the other a service account).

It's normal that the file is not found, since it is not shared with the other account. The service account is not you, so creating a file with your regular account doesn't give access to your service account, and vice versa.

#### Solution:

Call [Permissions: create](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/permissions/create) **with the same account with which you created the spreadsheet** if you want other accounts to have access to it.

For example, if you wanted to make it public, the request body would be:

```
{
  "role": "reader", // Or "writer"? Depends on what you want
  "type": "anyone"
}
```

Or, if you wanted to share with a certain account, it would be:

```
{
  "role": "reader", // Or "writer"? Depends on what you want 
  "type": "user",
  "emailAddress": "your_email_address"
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, but I dont know how to call with service account with which I created spreadsheet and I think it is my main problem.

Comment: Well if were able to create the file with the service account (`I created a spreadsheet using Google Sheets API with service account`) how come you don't know how to use the service account again? Can you clarify this?